# Reading csv with several subgroups

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a csv-file that contains "pivot-like" data that I would like to store into a `pandas DataFrame`. The original data file is divided using different number of whitespaces to differentiate between the level in the pivot-data like so:

```
Text that I do not want to include,,
,Text that I do not want to include,Text that I do not want to include
,header A,header B
Total,100,100
A,,2.15
   a1,,2.15
B,,0.22
   b1,,0.22
"      slightly longer name"...,,0.22
         b3,,0.22
C,71.08,91.01
   c1,57.34,73.31
      c2,5.34,6.76
         c3,1.33,1.67
            x1,0.26,0.33
            x2,0.26,0.34
            x3,0.48,0.58
            x4,0.33,0.42
         c4,3.52,4.33
            x5,0.27,0.35
            x6,0.21,0.27
            x7,0.49,0.56
            x8,0.44,0.47
            x9,0.15,0.19
            x10,,0.11
            x11,0.18,0.23
            x12,0.18,0.23
            x13,0.67,0.85
            x14,0.24,0.2
            x15,0.68,0.87
         c5,0.48,0.76
            x16,,0.15
            x17,0.3,0.38
            x18,0.18,0.23
      d2,6.75,8.68
         d3,0.81,1.06
            x19,0.3,0.38
            x20,0.51,0.68
Others,24.23,0
N/A,,
"Text that I do not want to include(""at all"") ",,
```

(It looks aweful, but you should be able to paste in e.g. Notepad to see it a bit clearer)

Basically, there are only two columns `a` and `b`, but the rows are indented using `0`, `3`, `6`, `9`, ... etc whitespaces to differentiate between the levels. So for instance,

- zero level, the main group, `A` has `0` spaces,
- first level `a1` has `3` spaces,
- second level `a2` has `6` spaces,
- third level `a3` has `9` spaces and
- fourth and final level has `12` spaces with the corresponding values for columns `a` and `b` respectively.

I would now like to be able to read and group this data on these levels in order to create a new summarizing DataFrame, with columns corresponding to these different levels, looking like:

```
 Level 4    Diff(a,b)   Level 0  Level 1     Level 2     Level 3
 x7         525         C        c1          c2          c3
 x5         -0.03       A        a1          a22         NaN
 x4         -0.04       A        a1          a22         NaN
 x8         -0.08       C        c1          c2          c3
 …
```

Any clue on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: so a DataFrame with only the level 4 entries?

Comment: Basically yes, but each level 4 entry has a column corresponding to the levels above it (i.e. level 0, 1, 2 and 3). So some kind of "unpivoting" using level 4 as reference "backwards" in the level-chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to split this into different functions

1. read the file
2. parse the lines
3. generate the 'tree'
4. construct the `DataFrame`

## Parse the lines

```
def parse_file(file):
    import ast
    import re
    pat = re.compile(r'^( *)(\w+),([\d.]+),([\d.]+)$')
    for line in file:
        r = pat.match(line)
        if r:
            spaces, label, a, b = r.groups()
            diff = ast.literal_eval(a) - ast.literal_eval(b)
            yield len(spaces)//3, label, diff
```

Reads each line, yields the `level`, 'label' and `diff` using a regular expression. I use `ast` to convert the string to `int` or `float`

## Generate the tree

```
def parse_lines(lines):
    previous_label = list(range(5))
    for level, label, diff in lines:
        previous_label[level] = label
        if level == 4:
            yield tuple(previous_label), diff
```

Initiates a `list` of length 5, and then overwrites the level this node is on.

## Construct the `DataFrame`

```
with StringIO(file_content) as file:
    lines = parse_file(file)
    index, data = zip(*parse_lines(lines))
    idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index, names=[f'level_{i}' for i in range(len(index[0]))])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Diff(a,b)': list(data)}, index=idx)
```

Opens the file, constructs the index and generates the `DataFrame` with the different levels in the index. If you don't want this, you can add a `.reset_index()` or construct the `DataFrame` slightly different

> ```
> df
> ```

```
level_0 level_1 level_2 level_3 level_4 Diff(a,b)
A   a1  a2  a3  x1  -0.07
A   a1  a2  a3  x2  -0.08000000000000002
A   a1  a22 a3  x3  -0.04999999999999999
A   a1  a22 a3  x4  -0.04000000000000001
A   a1  a22 a3  x5  -0.03
A   a1  a22 a3  x6  -0.06999999999999998
C   c1  c2  c3  x7  525.0
C   c1  c2  c3  x8  -0.08000000000000002
```

## alternative for missing levels

```
def parse_lines(lines):
    labels = [None] * 5
    previous_level = None
    for level, label, diff in lines:
        labels[level] = label
        if level == 4:
            if previous_level < 3:
                labels = labels[:previous_level + 1]  + [None] * (5 - previous_level)
                labels[level] = label
            yield tuple(labels), diff
        previous_level = level
```

the items under `a22` don't seem to have a `level_3`, so it copies that from the previous. If this is unwanted, you can take this variation

> ```
> df
> ```

```
level_0 level_1 level_2 level_3 level_4 Diff(a,b)
C   c1  c2  c3  x1  -0.07
C   c1  c2  c3  x2  -0.08000000000000002
C   c1  c2  c3  x3  -0.09999999999999998
C   c1  c2  c3  x4  -0.08999999999999997
C   c1  c2  c4  x5  -0.07999999999999996
C   c1  c2  c4  x6  -0.060000000000000026
C   c1  c2  c4  x7  -0.07000000000000006
C   c1  c2  c4  x8  -0.02999999999999997
C   c1  c2  c4  x9  -0.04000000000000001
C   c1  c2  c4  x11 -0.05000000000000002
C   c1  c2  c4  x12 -0.05000000000000002
C   c1  c2  c4  x13 -0.17999999999999994
C   c1  c2  c4  x14 0.03999999999999998
C   c1  c2  c4  x15 -0.18999999999999995
C   c1  c2  c5  x17 -0.08000000000000002
C   c1  c2  c5  x18 -0.05000000000000002
C   c1  d2  d3  x19 -0.08000000000000002
C   c1  d2  d3  x20 -0.17000000000000004
```

Comment: seems to be a problem with names=[f'level_{i}' for i in range(len(index[0]))]

Comment: the `f'...'` is a python 3.6 feature, so you might need to change the way the labels are named on a previous version

Comment: it works like a clock! However, when reading a .csv file it seems to be some issue. Guess its because that sort of file actually has commas in it?

Comment: you will have to change the regular expression. Why didn't you put a piece of the original file in the original question? splitting on comma's is a lot easier than the regular expression

Comment: pardon. I though the first line where I write "I have a csv-file..." was sufficient, but indeed the given example is just plain text with no commas. Terribly sorry. Let me change the given data into the actual file look.

Comment: you just have to change the regex in `parse_file`to `pat = re.compile(r'^( *)(\w+),([\d.]+),([\d.]+)$')`. Notice the missing `x10` since that has only 1 value (so no diff).